# Accessing valid JSON array after sending JSONP request? (Polymer)

Tags: json, ajax, polymer, jsonp

Back again. To get around the CORS issue, I'm now using an alternative Polymer element ([byutv-jsonp](http://coderfin.github.io/byutv-jsonp/components/byutv-jsonp/)) instead of iron-ajax. As you can see, it's successfully returning a valid JSON response, but now I can't seem to access it, and there's a syntaxerror which makes me think I need to stringify back into JSON...? Not really sure.

```
  <template is="dom-bind">

    <byutv-jsonp  
      auto 
      url="https://api.bookeo.com/v2/bookings/" 
      params='
        {
        "secretKey":"xxxxxxxxxxx", 
        "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ,
        "startTime": "2016-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
        "endTime": "2016-08-16T00:00:00.000Z"
        }' 
       last-response="{{lastResponse}}"
       on-response="handleResponse"
       debounce-duration="300"></byutv-jsonp>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lastResponse}}">
      <div>{{item.title}}</div>
    </template>

  </template>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Where is `lastResponse` being set? It looks like you're setting your last response to `items`. Which, I don't see being used anywhere.

Comment: @Anthony Ok I think I had a mistake in there for last-response, which I fixed above, so now my code matches the official [demo](https://github.com/coderfin/byutv-jsonp/blob/master/demo/index.html) (line #60) but still, having the same issue

Comment: The response is not valid JSONP.  It doesn't look like bookeo supports JSONP.  https://www.bookeo.com/api/protocol/  Without this support byutv-jsonp will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with your json data. You're trying to access `title` of your object, but it's nested within an array and a parent object. This should work based on the json object you've shown

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lastResponse.data[0]}}">
  <div>{{item.title}}</div>
</template>
```